# Listing all the files inside a folder in Javascript FileReader API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filereader

I have an interesting problem I thought I could solve easily but it turned out to be a massive work. Basically I need to enumerate all the files inside a given folder, even files inside subfolders of course.

I wrote a recursive function using `readEntries()` just to find out that the function doesn't necessarily return all the entries, it has to be called again until the returned array is empty (I guess they made it like this for performance reasons)

So here my recursive function:

```
var listOfFiles = [];

function readcontents(folder) {
    function readsome(reader) {
        reader.readEntries(function(entries) {
            for (var entry of entries) {
                if (entry.isDirectory) {
                    readsome(entry.createReader())
                } else {
                    listOfFiles.push(entry);
                }
            }
            if (entries.length) {
                readsome(reader)
            }
        })
    }
    readsome(folder.createReader())
}

readcontents(folder);
// here I should wait and then use the listOfFiles array
```

Now, `readEntries()` is asynchronous so how can I detect when the tree parsing is done? I need to wait for all the asynchronous calls to end and **only then** proceed with using the `listOfFiles`

**EDIT**

So far I received comments about using promises which sounds "promising".. so here my first guess on how to use it, feel free to comment

```
   var listOfFiles = [];

    function readcontents(folder) {
      function readsome(reader) {
        reader.readEntries(function(entries) {
          for(var entry of entries) {
            if(entry.isDirectory) {
              readsome(entry.createReader())
            } else {
                listOfFiles.push(entry);
                defer.resolve();
            }
          }
          if(entries.length) {
            readsome(reader)
          }
        })
      }
      readsome(folder.createReader())

      return defer.promise;
    }

    defer = $q.defer(); // <- global object
    readcontents(item).then(function(){
       // use the array
    }
```

Is that correct so far?

Comment: Have you tried using async/await or promises?

Comment: I tried using promises. It didn't work for some reason, I get a variable length array. E.g. with a folder of 1000 items, I get 735 sometimes, next time I get 324 etc.. Could you please show me how to properly use promises?

Comment: @Luca please have a look at my edit

Comment: Show us what `createReader()` does

Comment: @charlietfl createReader() is a method of the object "item", nothing to show here, is provided by Javascript itself

Comment: Then what part is asynchronous? What is `reader`?

Comment: @charlietfl readEntries()

Comment: So this is part of FileReader API? You left out some important details

Comment: reason for -1 ?

Comment: Forget about votes and update question with specifics about what these methods do, what they return and where they come from. You also never mentioned in beginning that this was run in angular environment

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the question with the version implementing promises. Is that correct?

Comment: No... for a loop you need an array of promises and return `$q.all()` and you don't create a global promise and `createReader` needs to return a promise but no idea where that method comes from or what `reader` is

Comment: @charlietfl could you please post the correct answer?

Comment: Not without more explanation of what `reader` is. Don't recognize those methods like `readEntries` or `createReader`. What are you passing in as `folder`??

Comment: For performance reasons it's better to stick to native promises and convert resulting promise with $q.resolve() in the end.

Comment: @charlietfl It is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your's problem is how to behave with the asynchronous callback, that's the solution: 
[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Basically you need to put in the `function.then(callbackfunction);` all the work need to be done **after** the returned value. 
If you want to do your work after the line

```
readcontents(folder);

// here I should wait and then use the listOfFiles array
```

you can return a promise from this function then again apply a asynchronous callback logic.

Comment: Ok, but if I declare a "var defer = $q.defer()" object, how can I call .resolve() on the defer object from within the callbacks? I don't see the object from the callback...

Comment: correct, $q is the angular provider for promises -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q